# If Rownumber = 1 and Condition Then Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a question about a sql result and how to achieve the following.

[image: Screenshot of Resultset]

In the Screenshot, there is a Rownumber for every ID, and every ID has another column which has a status 'old' or 'processed'. What i want is, if the RN is = 1 and the Status is processed, than all other RN of this ID should also have the status 'processed'.

Is there a possibility to achieve this in sql?

```
SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [NODE_NAME]
ORDER by REPORTING_RELEVANT_STATUS_ID DESC, BILLING_PERIOD DESC)
      ,[CI_EQUIPMENT_ID] AS ID_PART
      ,[REPORTING_RELEVANT_STATUS_ID] AS REPORTING_RELEVANT
      ,[BILLING_PERIOD]
     , [NODE_NAME]
        FROM Table
```

Comment: The least you could do is post the data with the column names. Please edit your question to include the relevant table DDL and the sample data as DML.

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: Second column value is different. I suppose it is `NODE_NAME` which is used by you to partition `row_number` by. If you're expecting value `13` there - remove `partition by` from `row_number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your query in CTE? then JOIN it with actual table:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [NODE_NAME]
ORDER by REPORTING_RELEVANT_STATUS_ID DESC, BILLING_PERIOD DESC)
      ,[CI_EQUIPMENT_ID] AS ID_PART
      ,[REPORTING_RELEVANT_STATUS_ID] AS REPORTING_RELEVANT
      ,[BILLING_PERIOD]
     , [NODE_NAME]
        FROM Table
)

SELECT  t.[CI_EQUIPMENT_ID] AS ID_PART,
        CASE WHEN c.RN is NOT NULL THEN c.REPORTING_RELEVANT ELSE t.[REPORTING_RELEVANT_STATUS_ID] END AS REPORTING_RELEVANT,
        t.[BILLING_PERIOD],
        t.[NODE_NAME]
FROM Table t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM cte
    WHERE RN = 1 AND REPORTING_RELEVANT = 'PROCESSED'
) as c
    ON c.ID_PART = t.[CI_EQUIPMENT_ID]
```

Comment: Hi guys, thx for your help, i was just creating the DDL for the table, and then the answer was already there. The solution with the CTE works fine.

Comment: Great! If any of answers were helpful feel free to upvote/accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

- Creating common table expression
- Updating the CTE values based on RN=1 and Status=Processed. using the Self Join

here:

```
;with CTE (RN,ID_PART,REPORTING_RELEVANT,BILLING_PERIOD,NODE_NAME) AS
(

  SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [NODE_NAME]
            ORDER by REPORTING_RELEVANT_STATUS_ID DESC, BILLING_PERIOD DESC)
      ,[CI_EQUIPMENT_ID] AS ID_PART
      ,[REPORTING_RELEVANT_STATUS_ID] AS REPORTING_RELEVANT
      ,[BILLING_PERIOD]
      , [NODE_NAME]
  FROM Table
)
Update CTE1
  set CTE1.Status='Processed'
from CTE CTE1 inner join CTE CTE2
  on CTE1.ID_PART=CTE2.ID_PART
where CTE2.RN=1 and CTE2.Status='Processed'
```

Comment: Thank @Ivan for editing. Did not know how to format it to look good.